# How do I PIVOT a set of columns based on a specific column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have columns of aggregated data and want to PIVOT them to my 'TYPE' column.

My data looks like this

```
ID          Country TYPE        Approved  Dispursed Payments  Amend  Deob
----------  ------- ----------  --------  --------- --------  -----  ----
40002-0086  US      Republic       79802  66163.05         0      0     0
40022-0002  Russia  Sultanate     456435         0      3000   9789   578
40002-0002  Nkorea  Dictatorship   50000     50000         0      0   789
40001-0001  Malta   Democracy     200000         0         0    456     0
40016-0013  UAE     Monarchy       65456    559542         0      0     0
40001-0002  Egypt   Federal       250000    250000         0      0    56
40002-0012  Canada  Parliamentary   7898      2000         0    789     0
```

And I am trying to make it look like this

```
ID  Country Republic Approved   Republic Disbursed  Republic Repaid Sultanate Approved  Sultanate Disbursed Federal Approved    Federal Disbursed   Monarchy Payments
44408   UAE  52,624,624.00  854,046.73   678,678.00      684,829.00      684,751.98      -       -       -   
41898   Canada   23,423,423.00   3,454,345.00    58,810.00   783,766.15      783,766.15      453,654,423.00      8,368,354.00    386,836.00
```

I am trying to use the PIVOT operator

This is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT 'ID' AS ID,   
[Republic Approved],[Republic Disbursed],[Republic Repaid],[Sultanate Approved],[Sultanate Disbursed],[Federal Approved],[Federal Disbursed],[Monarchy Payments]

FROM  
(SELECT ID, Country   
    FROM Table.ID) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
[TYPE]  
FOR ID, Country IN ([Republic Approved],[Republic Disbursed],[Republic Repaid],[Sultanate Approved],[Sultanate Disbursed],[Federal Approved],[Federal Disbursed],[Monarchy Payments]
 )  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: I suggest you fix up your formatting so users trying to help can read. Column headers should align with column values

Comment: Where are those IDs coming from? Where are those values coming from?

Comment: You'll probably have to unpivot on your numerical columns first then pivot again on type

Comment: Im putting an answer together, but to be sure, you are not pivoting on ID. You are pivoting on both "ID" and "Country" correct? Second, if UAE is a Monarchy as your first dataset states, why would they have a value pivoted under "Republic" values in your second, sample dataset? Essentially, the first dataset makes sense, but I do not understand the 2nd. This makes me think you are maybe not correctly stating what you want? Need to be sure before I provide some help. Not sure how to help yet.

Comment: Any of these solutions work for you?  Remember to accept an answer if one works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pivot multiple ways, you'll have to aggregate each individually.  Note that in the code below, if the 'type' condition in the case statement is not met, null is returned.  So the aggregations (I'm using sum here) will only aggregate over that type.

```
select    id,
          country,
          [Republic Approved] = sum(case when type = 'republic' then approved end),
          [Republic Disbursed] = sum(case when type = 'republic' then disbursed end),
          ...,
          [Sultanate Approved] = sum(case when type = 'sultanate' then approved end),
          ...
from      sourceTable
group by  id, 
          country
```

I'm making some assumptions on what you really want here though, as your stated desired results implies there's more data in your dataset.

Alternatively, you could first unpivot on those payment type columns, concatenate the resulting names with the government type, and then pivot on the concatenated names.  But this is going to be less performant and probably less readable, though possibly you'll get away with fewer characters typed (never the wisest goal).

Comment: Pivot can be difficult to visualize. I suggest this method of pivoting to new users. Much more clear on what the t-sql is doing. This works the same and can be easier to understand. This is what I figured the OP wanted but it doesn't match his second data set.

Comment: @jamie, I think many noted that his second dataset doesn't mesh well with what he seems to be otherwise asking for.  So I took a risk and assumed that he was only making up sample result data and really just wanted to convey the column schema.  Regarding the pivot, even more than visualization, this approach usually performs better.  And what's more, OP is trying to pivot multiple columns, so traditional pivot syntax won't work, unless you unpivot first.

Comment: Agreed and agreed. The only downside I've seen with this method is the typing :) but that can be worked around by creating a very large statement (like yours but with several dozen or hundreds of columns) with a query using the information_schema views. save the fingers! :)

Comment: @jamie, when I'm forced to use dynamic sql inside sql server, it's often for what you describe.  Just keep in mind that the SQL Server query engine is not as good as optimizing dynamic sql.  Also, you'll have to fend against sql injection.  But in many circumstances it's the more reasonable approach.

Comment: You are correct, but I was not referring to dynamic SQL. Just about creating a large, repetitive select clause using a query of information_schema. I would die if I had to type a statement like yours out on a very wide table. Send results to text in results pane and copy and paste that big select cause into your procedure or query.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to `UNPIVOT` the data via a `CROSS APPLY` and then `PIVOT`

This is assuming you don't need a DYNAMIC Pivot

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (  
        Select ID
              ,Country
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable
         Cross Apply ( values ([Type]+' Approved' ,[Approved])
                             ,([Type]+' Dispursed',[Dispursed])
                             ,([Type]+' Payments' ,[Payments])
                             ,([Type]+' Amend'    ,[Amend])
                             ,([Type]+' Deob'     ,[Deob])
                     ) B(Item,Value)
        ) src
 Pivot ( sum(value) for Item in ( [Republic Approved]
                                 ,[Republic Disbursed]
                                 ,[Republic Repaid]
                                 ,[Sultanate Approved]
                                 ,[Sultanate Disbursed]
                                 ,[Federal Approved]
                                 ,[Federal Disbursed]
                                 ,[Monarchy Payments]  
                                 ) ) pvt
```

**Just to help with the Visualization**

The `src` data **"feeding"** the pivot would look something like this...

[image]

Comment: Kudos for unpivoting using Cross Apply instead of Unpivot.

Comment: @pwilcox Thanks.  You get a little more control via the CROSS APPLY.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fan of this solution but it will give you what you need

```
WITH CTE AS 
  (SELECT ID,Country,Type+'-'+Status AS Type, Quantity 
   FROM Table
   UNPIVOT
    (
    Quantity FOR Status IN ([Approved],[Dispursed],[Payments],[Amend],[Deob])
    ) as up
) 
SELECT ID,Country,[Republic-Approved],[Republic-Dispursed],[Republic-Payments],[Republic-Amend],[Republic-Deob],
                               [Sultanate-Approved],[Sultanate-Dispursed],[Sultanate-Payments],[Sultanate-Amend],[Sultanate-Deob]
FROM CTE
PIVOT ( 
    SUM(Quantity) FOR Type IN ([Republic-Approved],[Republic-Dispursed],[Republic-Payments],[Republic-Amend],[Republic-Deob],
                               [Sultanate-Approved],[Sultanate-Dispursed],[Sultanate-Payments],[Sultanate-Amend],[Sultanate-Deob])
   )p
```